# JRuby on Rails on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have an Jruby on Rails app that I'd love to deploy on Google App Engine. Does anyone know if it's even still possible to deploy a Rails app on GAE?

I know there were a bunch of gems such as datamappers (because GAE uses a non-relational database), but the support seems to have suddenly stopped in late 2011, and there's pretty much nothing since, anywhere. I know that since 2011, Google Cloud SQL has become available - so maybe we can use that with GAE for our data storage?